# Python Pandas time difference between string and series

Tags: python, pandas, time, difference

I am getting the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py
> in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
> 142     try:
> --> 143         result = expressions.evaluate(op, left, right)
> 144     except TypeError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py
> in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
> 232         if use_numexpr:
> --> 233             return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore
> 234     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py
> in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
> 118     if result is None:
> --> 119         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
> 120
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py
> in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
> 67     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
> ---> 68         return op(a, b)
> 69
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and
> 'builtin_function_or_method'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 NVAX['snap_ts'].dt.time - datetime.strptime('14:30:00', '%H:%M:%S').time
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in
> new_method(self, other)
> 63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
> 64
> ---> 65         return method(self, other)
> 66
> 67     return new_method
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/**init**.py in
> wrapper(left, right)
> 341         lvalues = extract_array(left, extract_numpy=True)
> 342         rvalues = extract_array(right, extract_numpy=True)
> --> 343         result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
> 344
> 345         return left._construct_result(result, name=res_name)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py
> in arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
> 188     else:
> 189         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
> --> 190             res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
> 191
> 192     return res_values
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py
> in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
> 148             #  will handle complex numbers incorrectly, see GH#32047
> 149             raise
> --> 150         result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
> 151
> 152     if is_cmp and (is_scalar(result) or result is NotImplemented):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py
> in masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
> 94     else:
> 95         if not is_scalar(y):
> ---> 96             raise TypeError(
> 97                 f"Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type { type(y) }"
> 98             )
>
> TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class
> 'builtin_function_or_method'>

when performing this:

```
df['snap_ts'].dt.time - datetime.strptime('14:30:00', '%H:%M:%S')
```

df['snap_ts'].dt.time is equivalent to this:

```
0         14:30:10
1         14:30:20
2         14:30:30
3         14:30:40
4         14:30:50
            ...   
157763    19:59:20
157764    19:59:30
157765    19:59:40
157766    19:59:50
157767    20:00:00
Name: snap_ts, Length: 157768, dtype: object
```

and it's a pandas.core.series.Series

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like an object(from the dtype) and not a datetime series

Comment: sammywemmy then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for that?

```
df['snap_ts'].sub(pd.Timedelta('14:30:00')).dt.time
```